# How to append javascript variable inside PHP tag?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to write a javascript function inside PHP tag, but I do not know the exact syntax. Can anyone help? I am trying to concat the variable named "var1". But I am getting error.

### index.php

```
<?php
echo '<script>
demo(1);
function demo(var){
   const var1=1;
   const ptag=document.getElementById("content"+var1);
}
</script>';
?>
```

Comment: "_But I am getting error_" _What_ error would that be? Escape your quotes. `var` in your function is unused. Your JS doesn't really do anything

Comment: Try using single quotes (`'`) for the php `echo''` part and use double quotes (`""`) for the javascript code, here: `"content"`, to avoid conflict between the two.

Comment: Syntax error. perhaps there is an error in single quotes or double quotes or the concatenation sign

Comment: okay I removing the "content". But can I get the actual code?

Comment: dont remove it just use double quotes (`""`) around the `"content"`.

Comment: okay and shall the "+" concatenation works?

Comment: yes in javascript you concatenate with the `+`-operator

Comment: You are not even inserting any PHP values dynamically there, so why output this via echo in the first place? This is a prime example for when you should just write the actual HTML code, outside of `<?php ... ?>` tags. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: 'var' is a reserved word: can't use that as a param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="content1">1th</p>
<p id="content2">2th</p>
<p id="content3">3th</p>
<p id="content4">4th</p>
<p id="content5">5th</p>


 <?php
        echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            function demo(num){
              const paragraphTag = document.getElementById('content'+ num);
            }
            demo(1)
            </script>
        ";
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

#### what is your mistakes :

1. it's better to use function after declaration
2. you can't use `var` as a name of variable it's reserved key
3. I think you want to pass number to function and use that number for getting specific `p` element, if it is so you don't need `var1`
4. finally use single quotes `"` for the php `echo` and single quotes `'` for `content`

**and maybe you need this code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="content1">1th</p>
<p id="content2">2th</p>
<p id="content3">3th</p>
<p id="content4">4th</p>
<p id="content5">5th</p>


<button onclick="demo()">click here</button>


 <?php
        $num = 1;
        echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            function demo(){
              const paragraphTag = document.getElementById('content'+ $num);
              paragraphTag.textContent = 'selected'
            }
            </script>
        ";
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```